# preventing maxLength on a input type number

Tags: angularjs, input, maxlength

I took me a while to figure this one out, but can someone post a cleaner method for limiting the number of digits in an input type='number'.  One of the issues is that errors are thrown if $scope.variable = null....meaning nothing in the input field.

```
<input type="number" model='modalName' ng-change="monitorLength('modalName',16)">
```

JS:

```
  $scope.monitorLength = function (model,maxLength) {
    if ($scope[model] != null) {  // prevent error on empty input field
      var len = $scope[model].toString() ;  // convert to a string
      if (len.length > maxLength) {  //evaluate string length
        $scope[model] = parseInt(len.substring(0, maxLength));  
        // convert back to number or warning is thrown on input value not being a number
      }
    }
  }
```

I then needed to expand up on this to account for number only, preventing any non-digit characters include '.' and ',' symbols:

```
  var reg = new RegExp(/^\d+$/) ;
  $scope.monitorLength = function (modal,maxLength) {
    if ($scope[modal] != null) {
      var len = $scope[modal].toString() ;
      if (len.length > maxLength) {
        $scope[modal] = parseInt(len.substring(0, maxLength));
      } else if (!reg.test(len)) {
        $scope[modal] = parseInt(len.substring(0, len.length-2));
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there way to extract the ng-modal that was responsible for calling the ng-change?  so the call would only have to be: `ng-change="monitorLength(10)"`.  And then in the function somehow dynamically retrieve the calling ng-modal?

Comment: Can you not just use `min` and `max` [attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_max.asp) on the input element? There are very few browsers which do not support that

Comment: Not for angular, since it wraps elements and binds them to the $scope specific HTML input parameters do not work or they are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" max="99" onkeypress="if (this.value.length >= 2) return false;"/>
```

OR

```html
<!--maxlength="10"-->
<input type="number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==10) return false;" />
```

Answer (score -1):

this is a cleaner method for limiting the number, using ngMaxlength for that:

```
<input type="number" model='modalName' ng-maxlength="16">
```

You can find more attributes and info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D)

Comment: wouldn't it be `ng-maxlength` as the page you are linking to suggests?

Comment: sorry copy paste from chart, you are right its ng-maxlength

Comment: no, ng-maxlength doesn't actually prevent the user from typing more than 16 characters.  Only 16 characters are stored in the $scope.variable...but visually the user will still see more than 16 characters.  The above is a method to prevent character run-over in the actual input field.

Comment: From the angular documentation: `Note: This directive is also added when the plain maxlength attribute is used, with two differences:
ngMaxlength does not set the maxlength attribute and therefore HTML5 constraint validation is not available.`

Answer (score -1):

> Is there way to extract the ng-modal that was responsible for calling the ng-change?

Yes. You can define a directive and require the `ngModelController`.

```
.directive('maxNum', function(){
    return {
        require: '^ngModel',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs){
            // here you can add formatters/parsers to the ngModel 
            // to affect the change on the ngModel.$viewValue.

        }
    }
})
```

As @rolinger stated on the other answer, using the built in directives will not prevent the use from entering non-valid characters, they simply mark the model as being invalid.